# Tratamento de variaveis em HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variáveis, url

Olá... O mundo HTLM / JAVASSCRIPT / PHP é totalmente novo para mim. Como iniciante, conto com a ajuda de vocês para desenvolver um pequeno projeto.
Vamos lá...

Tenho uma página INDEX.HTML que recebe um valor via URL. Consegui ler esse valor usando uma função chamada CAPTURAPARAMETROURL() que peguei neste forum. Agora preciso abrir uma página chamada CADASTRO.HTML quando o usuário clicar em INSCRIÇÃO passando esse valor obtido pela função.

Quem pode me ajudar?

O código do INDEX.HTML é este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <title>MEU SITE</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->

</head>

<body background="images/bg/bg2.jpg">


 <div class="container-meusite">

  <div class="wrap-meusite" >

   <div class="meusite-form-title" style="background-image: url(images/title.png);">
   </div>

                            <div class="container-meusite-form-btn">

                                <div class="container-meusite-form-btn">
    </div>

                            </div>

                                <center><button class="meusite-form-btn">
                                        <a href="cadastro.html?" style="color: #fff"><span>Inscri&ccedil;&atilde;o</span></a>


                                </button>

                                </br>

                            <button class="meusite-form-btn" >
                                <a href="termo.html" style="color: #fff"><span>
                                                    Termos de uso

                                                 </span></a>

                                </button></center>
                    </br>
 </div>
                </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

window.onload = CapturaParametrosUrl();

/* Captura parametros da URL com JS*/
function CapturaParametrosUrl() {
var url = window.location.href; //retorna a url da página

var res = url.split('?'); //tenta localizar o ?

if (res[1] !== undefined) {

var parametros = res[1].split('&'); //tenta localizar os & (pode haver mais de 1)

if (parametros[0] !== undefined) {
parametro0 = parametros[0].split('=');
parametro0 = parametro0[1];
var promocional = parametros[0]
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = parametro0;
}

if (parametros[1] !== undefined) {
parametro1 = parametros[1].split('=');
parametro1 = parametro1[1];
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += ', ' + parametro1;
}

if (parametros[2] !== undefined) {
parametro2 = parametros[2].split('=');
parametro2 = parametro2[1];
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += ', ' + parametro2;
}
}
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode ir concatenando os parâmetros e depois alterar o `href` do link adicionando os parâmetros.

Primeiro, retire o `?` do link, deixando apenas `href="cadastro.html"`:

```
<a href="cadastro.html" style="color: #fff"><span>Inscri&ccedil;&atilde;o</span></a>
```

Em seguida use o código abaixo alterado (veja explicações no código):

```
window.onload = CapturaParametrosUrl();

/* Captura parametros da URL com JS*/
function CapturaParametrosUrl() {
   var url = window.location.href; //retorna a url da página

   var res = url.split('?'); //tenta localizar o ?

   var params = ''; // cria uma variável para os parâmetros

   if (res[1] !== undefined) {

      var parametros = res[1].split('&'); //tenta localizar os & (pode haver mais de 1)

      if (parametros[0] !== undefined) {
         parametro0 = parametros[0].split('=');
         parametro0 = parametro0[1];
         var promocional = parametros[0]
         //document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = parametro0;

         params += "?param1="+parametro0; // adiciona o 1º parâmetro
      }

      if (parametros[1] !== undefined) {
         parametro1 = parametros[1].split('=');
         parametro1 = parametro1[1];
         //document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += ', ' + parametro1;
         params += "&param2="+parametro1; // adiciona o 2º parâmetro
      }

      if (parametros[2] !== undefined) {
         parametro2 = parametros[2].split('=');
         parametro2 = parametro2[1];
         //document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += ', ' + parametro2;
         params += "&param3="+parametro2; // adiciona o 3º parâmetro
      }
   }

   if(params != ""){ // se houve parâmetros, atualizo o href do link com eles
      document.querySelector("a[href='cadastro.html']").href = "cadastro.html"+params;
   }
}
```

No exemplo acima, eu utilizei os nomes dos parâmetros como `param1`, `param2` e `param3`. Esses nomes você pode alterar com os que desejar, é só altera-los no código.

Comment: Deu certinho! Passou corretamente o parâmetro. Agora, acho que eu deveria abrir outro tópico de pergunta mas não custa perguntar: Posso usar esse mesmo método para pegar o parâmetro passado para página CADASTRO.HTML e inserir esse valor num INPUT? Como ficaria essa linha neste caso?

 document.querySelector("a[href='cadastro.html']").href

Comment: Pode usar a mesma função. Para incluir no input teria que mudar o seletor para `document.querySelector("input").value = params`... no lugar de `input` você teria que colocar uma id ou classe, ou pegar pelo name etc.

Comment: Show de bola! Deu tudo certo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Onde marco isso? Estou procurando aqui e não acho... rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: achei! valeu....